# Is it possible for Jquery to force select to think thank it changed even though i didn't click on it?

Tags: jquery

guys i was wondering if i can force a select to think that it changed even though i didn't click on it. i have the following code.

```
<select id="foo">
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
</select>

<select id="foo2">
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3">c</option>
</select>
```

and below is the Jquery

```
$("#foo").change(function(){
    $selected = $("#foo option:selected").text();
        $('#foo2 option:contains('+$selected+')').prop('selected',true);
});
```

what i want to do is when i select option from select with ID foo it should search select with ID foo2 if it has the same text then select it if has it. my problem is that i want select ID foo2 to in a state of changed like i clicked on it.

here is my Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Fulfill/d3usdLcv/

any help will be appreciated
thank you in advance

Comment: Do you need it "in a state of changed" just so its change event is called or is there another reason?

Comment: include the jquery file in your fiddle. Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3usdLcv/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't select the option like this: If there are e.g. brackets in it, it won't work anymore. But anyway, you can just call `val()` on the second select list and pass the value of the desired option.

```
$("#foo").change(function(){
    var selected = $("#foo option:selected").text();
    $('#foo2').val($('#foo2 option:contains('+selected+')').first().val());
});
```

See:
https://jsfiddle.net/d3usdLcv/6/

Comment: See my answer mate

Comment: @Max, Are you seriously downvoting, because you answered it similary?

Comment: Yes, do not duplicate answers, keep SO cleaner

Comment: I was downvoted as well many times when answered similar with somebody. Then I removed my answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to achieve what you want. I used faster selectors that you in question.

```
$("#foo").change(function() {
    var fooValue = $(this).val();
    var $foo2 = $('#foo2');

    if ($foo2.find('option[value=' + fooValue + ']').length) {
      $foo2.val(fooValue);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3usdLcv/10/)

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to trigger an update on select is to set it's value. To do so you just have to get the value of foo2 with the matching text.

Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/d3usdLcv/9/

```
$("#foo").change(function(){
    var selected_text = $(this).find(':selected').text()

    var matching_value = ($("#foo2 option").toArray().filter(function(element) {
        return $(element).text() == selected_text
    })[0] || {}).value

    matching_value && $("#foo2").val(matching_value)
});
```